# Where does the Android System store the locations of applications on your homescreen /desktop

Tags: android, settings, preferences, homescreen, android-launcher

First, Does the android system store the "location" of apps when they are on your homescreen/ desktop.

For example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iyul9.png) has a photo of a homescreen with many apps. In that picture, you will notice apps have locations, IMDB, Gmail, Youtube, are all in their specific locations. Does the android system have a config/ system/ yml file that is accessible and readible somewhere in the system? 
My intention is to find out the locations of apps, record them, and find a way to re-post them or re-apply them if the icons on the screen were to get removed or taken off. If I can get the pointer/ location of the spot on the home screen where it is located, I can then read that (something like C4, or H2), then I can hopefully reverse engineer how to write the data as well.

The second question is, if the only way this 'magical' file I am looking for can be found is to use a separate Home launcher (Nova, Google Now Launcher, Go Launcher), are there any of them that you recommend asking for help as they are dev friendly?

Comment: "Does the android system store the "location" of apps when they are on your homescreen/ desktop" -- no. The app that *is* the "homescreen/desktop" stores that information.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. That would explain why updating an app can displace it sometimes. I assume then that accessing the location of its placement via every app is probably not feasible then. :/

Comment: "I assume then that accessing the location of its placement via every app is probably not feasible then" -- correct. Each home screen implementation is welcome to handle that however they want.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for hte help CommonsWare, if you copy and paste your response as an answer to the question I will be happy to click it as the answer and up some rep for ya!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the android system store the "location" of apps when they are on your homescreen/ desktop

No. The app that *is* the "homescreen/desktop" stores that information. Each home screen can do whatever it wants. It is eminently possible that some share a common heritage (e.g., the home screen from the Android Open Source Project) and therefore may share elements of a common implementation, but others are likely to have been made completely from scratch.

You might consider finding an open source home screen implementation and adding your features to it.

Comment: When one installs another home screen how does the other / new app have all the same exact icons then? There should be some shared storage.

Comment: @Gizmo: They both get the list of launchable activities from `PackageManager`. They both get wallpaper from the OS as well. On Android 8.1+ they get pinned shortcuts from the OS.